# jsf bean validation with dto and validation in entities

Tags: jsf, dto, bean-validation, entities

JSF is capable to automatically validate objects connected with form. F.e. with have entity Person with bean validation in there. We can populate entity with form using {form.entity.field}. JSF managed bean is forced to have entity with entity getter getEntity() (to do automatic validation using annotations in another object).

On the other side, such a solution is not preferable and I should use dtos in jsf managed beans. Unfortunately, I want bean validation logic keep only in one place - entity.

Is it possible to validate entity dto's with annotations from entity (not copying) automatically with jsf (no or little code, using embedded jsf bean validator for jsr-303)?

Comment: Why the extra DTO layer? It's causing the whole trouble. Just use entity as if it's DTO.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am working with such a code and I am curious, if it can be done easily. I have no other solution - only to deal with it ;P

Comment: Validation should be done on a service layer, not a presentation layer. The reason is that you can have many presentation interfaces – web, RESTful API, CLI, … that uses the same service layer.